# Google Spreadheet Script to save and load data to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all, thank you to the community for helping each other out!

I'm a teacher and i'm building a spreadsheet to use for grading students. More specifically, my spreadsheet has a couple of sheets: Input, Variables, Data (and for now 'Test') that contain the following:

**Input**

- Name selection (pulldownmenu using names list on Data-sheet) (cell B3)
- List of criteria with corresponding list of pulldown menu's that are set to
  yes/no (or other options, based on lists in Variables-sheet) (column D)
- Calculation of grades

**Variables**

- A couple of lists such as Yes/No, or Good/Average/Bad, etc for use in
  pulldownmenu's on the Input-sheet

**Data**

- A list of student names, for use in the pulldown menu for name
  selection on the Input-sheet

**Test**

- This sheet is used for testing my scripts

**Grades**

- This sheet is used for collecting student grades

To fully understand what I'm talking about, please take a look at the sheet in question here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IHdlEhjBLBEyqopbicthQLdaGxtH3_1gt1sNOvRlwgo/edit?usp=sharing

Now, the functionality (workflow) I'm looking for is the following:

1. On the Input sheet: I choose a student's name from the list, fill out his results (this sheet will calculate the grade) and click a save button. This will copy the results-column to the Test-sheet, where it will be pasted as a row behind the corresponding name.
   **So far so good** (I've managed to get this to work.)
2. At the same time the grades will have to be copied to the Grades-sheet. This is where it gets a bit confusing to me, for i need to have some way of selecting the grades from the Input-sheet. I was thinking i could select values based on cell backgroundcolor or FontSize or something similar, but i can't get it to work.
3. When the grades are saved in the Grades-sheet i will be able to use
   them in other sheets for the purpose of reviewing and comparing.
   When a students results have been entered and saved, i also need the
   option to load the data from the Test-sheet back into the Input
   sheet. So basically, this does the Save operation the other way
   around; it finds the correct data by comparing the selected name on
   the Input-sheet with the list of names on the Test-sheet and then
   copies the corresponding results row and pastes it as a column into
   the Input-sheet.

The code i have been using so far:

```
function Save() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');

  var studentName = sourceSheet.getRange('B3').getValue(); //returns the name of the current student
  var studentResult = sourceSheet.getRange(5,4,sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //returns the results of the current student

  var columnValues = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //returns all student names listed in first column of targetsheet
  var studentRow = findIndex(columnValues, studentName)+1;  //returns the rownumber where studentName was found
  var ResultInRow = col2row(sourceSheet.getRange(5,4,sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues()); //transpose the column data to row data

 targetSheet.getRange(studentRow,2,1,sourceSheet.getLastRow()).setValues(ResultInRow); //select cellrange and fill with the results 

}

function findIndex(columnValues, studentName) {
  for(var i=0, iLen=columnValues.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if(columnValues[i] == studentName) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}


function col2row(column) {
  return [column.map(function(row) {return row[0];})];
} 

function row2col(row) {
  return row[0].map(function(elem) {return [elem];});
}
```

My question is actually twofold:
First, since I'm not a coder by any measure, i'd like to know if my approach makes any sense, or if there is another--better--way of doing the same?
Second, can you please help me out with the code i need to select the grades *only*, preferably labeled by the Grade's name (i.e. the exercise's name)?

Comment: Hi there,I appreciate what you are doing- I looked at the spreadsheet and don't understand the language. Had a hard time understanding exactly what it is you are trying to do. I am not sure where the grades are, perhaps you can reword the question using the actual cell locations?

Comment: Sure! Sorry if I am unclear.
On the input sheet you can see I have some cells with a backgrond color. I would like to use a script to collect these in a seperate sheet called grades, in the following format:  

Studentname | Gradename 1 | grade | grade | grade | grade | grade | grade | Gradename 2 | grade | grade | grade | grade | grade | grade |

etc    

Or, using the current content:    

Studentname | Logo | 6.3 | 6.0 | 7.3 | 3.8 | 5.9 |  Website  | 8.0 | 7.2 | 6.5 | 7.2 | 7.2 |

Comment: If you currently press the save button, it copies column D to a row in sheet 'test', next to the corresponding name in the first column of the 'test' sheet

Comment: ok this is making more sense, so when you press the save button you would like also the row 8 &  row 42  copied over to the grades sheet including the students name?

Comment: The way I understand it is everything in G8:K (and L8 and L42) is a grade. Which of these do you need copied? Can you give an example of the desired output similar to what you have in Test already given the current input?

Comment: I've added the desired output to the Grades-sheet. It is a collection of the names of an assignment and the corresponding grades. This is always a set of one title and 6 grades, pasted one after the other. I've now correctly marked all the cells i need to copy in yellow on the Input-sheet.
Please note that the length of items in the B column can change, so I can't just select a specific cellnumber to copy. It needs to be selected based on some script that recognises what are actual grades (and title) in this sheet